# How Reordering instruction solve the data dependency?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I recently encountered a problem. I watch a video talking about data dependency. And the instructor says that by reordering the instruction can solve the data dependency issue. Example of Read after Write hazard:

```
A1 <- B1 + C1 
A2 <- A1 + B2
```

In this case, there are two stalls for second instruction. By reordering the instructions:

```
A2 <- A1 + B2 
A1 <- B1 + C1
```

we get rid of the Read after Write hazard. Technically is right. But, I wondering isn't the second approach is logically wrong and will introduce wrong result?

Please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, that would change the result and isn't a valid optimization unless you have other information that somehow makes that safe.  (i.e. that A was already equal to B1 + C1, in which case you should have just optimized it away instead of reordering).

(I assume "A" is the register and A1 / A2 are sequence numbers for a Static Single Assignment way of tracking value lifetimes.  i.e. A2 is the 2nd value that A has.)

Hopefully the video you're watching didn't suggest that's a way to *solve* the problem for the first case, just that it's a *different* example that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I wondering the idea of reordering the instruction is to pick another independent instruction (which will be executed anyway) to fill the gap? Therefore, we do not need to waste two clock cycles to wait and do nothing.

Comment: @YokJyeTang: sure, that would be how a compiler should schedule for an in-order CPU.  An out-of-order execution CPU can already do that for you, and do register renaming to hide WAW and WAR hazards, leaving RAW true dependencies as the only thing that really matters.  If there's enough instruction-level parallelism then you aren't bottlenecked by latency at all, though.